# Обращение к *.so по относительному пути

Tags: linux, c, разделяемые-библиотеки

Есть библиотека `libsvsynth.so`, идущая в комплекте с программой, которая её использует. Т.к. библиотека не устанавливается в систему (программа задумывалась, как физически переносимая), то к путь к ней в функции `dlopen` описывается как `./libsvsynth.so`.

При использовании:

```
$ ./prog
```

Всё работает - библиотека подключается. Однако, если написать

```
$ ./parent_dir/prog
```

То библиотека программой обнаружена не будет (как я понял, библиотека будет искаться в вызываемом каталоге)

Что же нужно сделать для того, чтобы программу можно было запускать без проблем из любого места, а не только из каталога с бинарником+библиотекой?

Comment: ну, я бы проверил, записывается ли в системе в `argv[0]` полное имя вызываемой программы, и если да - то находил бы из него путь, и добавлял имя библиотеки...

Comment: @Harry была такая идея, но чую, что есть способ проще

Comment: Добавить путь до библиотеки в переменую `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Итак, проблема была решена следующим образом: к программе всё же пришлось добавить shell-скрипт (`start.sh`) следующего содержания:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do
    DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
    SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
    [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE"
done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
cd $DIR
./prog $@
```

Затем делаем `chmod +x ./start.sh` и запускаем из любого каталога в системе

Comment: Это плохой вариант: вы теряете информацию о текущей директории, а потому для некоторых программ такой трюк неприменим.

Comment: @PavelMayorov готов принять ваше решение

Comment: Чем вас не устроил ответ от mymedia?

Comment: @Vidoom, а зачем вы там цикл накрутили? Можно же по относительному пути сменить текущий каталог. И почему вам не подойдёт вот такй сценарий: `cd -P $(dirname "$0") && ./prog "$@"` ? И кстати, обратите внимание на кавычки вокруг `$@`. Они будут важны, если аргумент содержит пробелы.

Answer (score 2):

#### наиболее простой вариант: скрипт-обёртка

можете рядом с программой приложить скрипт примерно такого содержания:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$(dirname "$0")" && ./prog
```

присвоить ему биты исполнимости:

```
$ chmod +x путь/к/этому/скрипту
```

и вызывать его из любого места файловой системы, указывая хоть относительный, хоть абсолютный путь.

#### более сложный вариант:

не линковать, а [динамически подгружать нужную библиотеку](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html) в процессе работы программы, предварительно [получив путь к выполняемому файлу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/933850/4827341) и дополнив его путём к библиотеке.

Comment: А нельзя ли обойтись без скриптов, только изменениями в коде?

Comment: @Vidoom, насколько я знаю, повлиять на загрузчик (в данном аспекте) «изнутри» программы невозможно. скрипт-обёртка (один из множества вариантов я и предложил) — наиболее простое решение «разрулить» ситуацию, когда местоположение требуемой библиотеки неизвестно на момент компиляции. другое известное мне решение (значительно более сложное) — [динамически подгружать нужную библиотеку](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html) прямо в коде программы.

Comment: так и всё и сделано. Проблема в том, что неизвестно, в каком каталоге будет находиться программа, поэтому при использовании "./lib" поиск библиотеки может происходить в другом каталоге. Я и спрашиваю, как это исправить

Comment: у вас в программе библиотека подгружается динамически? ну так и указывайте её местоположение, [получив путь к выполняемому файлу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/933850/4827341).

Comment: Вариант со скриптом-оберткой не является универсальным, потому что он теряет информацию о текущей директории.

Answer (score 2):

Развивая идею, предложенную в дополнении к ответу Александра Баракина, набросал пример функции, которая загружает динамическую библиотеку по пути файла, относительного текущего выполняемого файла вне зависимости от рабочего каталога или переменных окружения.

```
void* load_library(const char* r_path)
{
    if (r_path[0] == '/')
        return dlopen(r_path, RTLD_LAZY);

    char a_path[PATH_MAX] = {0};
    readlink("/proc/self/exe", a_path, sizeof a_path);
    char* last_slash = strrchr(a_path, '/');
    if (last_slash == NULL) {
        // в иных Unix-системах надо по-другому определять текущий бинарник
        errno = ENOSYS;
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(last_slash + 1, r_path);
    return dlopen(a_path, RTLD_LAZY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

При работе с библиотеками можно использовать возможности компилятора и указать путь где будет происходить поиск библиотеки

```
gcc -Wl,rpath,/usr/local/lib
```

если нет возможности слинковать программу с нужными путями можно использовать переменую

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

указав в ней пути поиска библиотеки.

Comment: Ни программа, ни библиотека не установлены в систему

Comment: Укажите в переменой `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` путь до этой папки и запускайте программу из любого каталога.

Comment: Каким образом это можно осуществить в коде?

Comment: @Vidoom Хотите сказать Вы не знаете в каком каталоге будет ваша программа ?

Comment: всё именно так. Известно лишь, что библиотека в одном каталоге с программой