# Компиляция библиотеки в корне проекта

Tags: c++, linux, c

Как в линуксе можно скомпилировать программу с библиотекой .so, чтобы при запуске программы, она использовала библиотеку, которая лежит в том же каталоге что и программа? !

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670146/178576

Comment: Зачем закрывать вопрос, если суют совсем другой вопрос и говорят что в нем есть ответ. Человек явно не знает что советует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать передать линкеру следующие аргументы: `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,'$ORIGIN'`. Однако не все сборки линукса содержат линкер, поддерживающий костыль `$ORIGIN`, так что в общем случае это не обязательно сработает.

Comment: `-L./ -Wl,-rpath=./ -lmylib` универсально без макросов

Comment: @NewView `./` это путь относительно текущей папки, а не относительно папки, где лежит программа

Comment: То есть, правильный способ будет загружать динамическую либу через dlopen ( "./libSDL2.so" )?

Comment: @xverizex "./libSDL2.so" это будет опять же, относительно текущей папки. Ну и библиотеки с С++ интерфейсом так использовать не получится

Comment: Обсалютно точно, но автор подразумевает что он и стартует с локальной папки. Если папка другая.. а если программу перенесут? Это путь в некуда.., брать надо путь из argv[0] в таком случае. При сборке можно родить любой Шелл скрипт/макро, или забить фиксированные пути

Comment: @NewView Автор нигде такого не подразумевает...

Comment: В случае линкера и загрузки библиотеки, если не ошибаюсь, `./` и есть путь где живёт программа, а не путь откуда она запущена, вроде так, strace можно посмотреть откуда при старте начинает искать. Сперва `./` потом user/lib потом system/lib. -rpath линкера дописывает фиксированный путь в начало к этим путям поиска.

Comment: @NewView Путь, где живет программа - это как раз `$ORIGIN`